# asyncio as_yielded from async generators

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, coroutine, control-flow

I'm looking to be able to yield from a number of async coroutines. Asyncio's `as_completed` is kind of close to what I'm looking for (i.e. I want any of the coroutines to be able to yield at any time back to the caller and then continue), but that only seems to allow regular coroutines with a single return.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import asyncio


async def test(id_):
    print(f'{id_} sleeping')
    await asyncio.sleep(id_)
    return id_


async def test_gen(id_):
    count = 0
    while True:
        print(f'{id_} sleeping')
        await asyncio.sleep(id_)
        yield id_
        count += 1
        if count > 5:
            return


async def main():
    runs = [test(i) for i in range(3)]

    for i in asyncio.as_completed(runs):
        i = await i
        print(f'{i} yielded')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

Replacing `runs = [test(i) for i in range(3)]` with `runs = [test_gen(i) for i in range(3)]` and for `for i in asyncio.as_completed(runs)` to iterate on each yield is what I'm after.

Is this possible to express in Python and are there any third party maybe that give you more options then the standard library for coroutine process flow?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [aiostream.stream.merge](http://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operators.html#aiostream.stream.merge):

```
from aiostream import stream

async def main():
    runs = [test_gen(i) for i in range(3)]
    async for x in stream.merge(*runs):
        print(f'{x} yielded')
```

Run it in a [safe context](http://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core.html#aiostream.core.Stream.stream) to make sure the generators are cleaned up properly after the iteration:

```
async def main():
    runs = [test_gen(i) for i in range(3)]
    merged = stream.merge(*runs)
    async with merged.stream() as streamer:
        async for x in streamer:
            print(f'{x} yielded')
```

Or make it more compact using [pipes](http://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operators.html#pipe-lining):

```
from aiostream import stream, pipe

async def main():
    runs = [test_gen(i) for i in range(3)]
    await (stream.merge(*runs) | pipe.print('{} yielded'))
```

More examples in the [documentation](http://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html).

---

**Adressing @nirvana-msu comment**

It is possible to identify the generator that yielded a given value by preparing sources accordingly:

```
async def main():
    runs = [test_gen(i) for i in range(3)]
    sources = [stream.map(xs, lambda x: (i, x)) for i, xs in enumerate(runs)]
    async for i, x in stream.merge(*sources):
        print(f'ID {i}: {x}')
```

Comment: this looks spot on, thank you. I'll give it a try later this evening and award you the answer.

Comment: @Vincent: This is exactly what I was looking for! I considered using `aioreactive` as well, `aiostream`'s source code is much more compact, and seems a lot easier to use and understand . Very good documentation as well! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Is there a way to know which generator the current value was yielded from?

Comment: One more question, if I may. Not sure if aiostream can help here, but how do I solve the same question in a simpler case - when I just have an iterable of coroutines (and not an iterable of asyc generators). I.e., just as in OP's example, when I do `for i in asyncio.as_completed(runs)` - how can I find out which coroutine the value was yielded from? Not sure if `stream.map` is relevant as we're not dealing with async generator here. I can manually wrap my asyc function in another one, but I'm wondering if there's a helper similar to `stream.map`.

Comment: If you want to avoid warnings such as ``AsyncIteratorContext is iterated outside of its context``, you must also protect the ``async for`` inside an ``async with aiostream.stream.merge(*sources).stream() as stream``. See https://github.com/vxgmichel/aiostream/issues/46 and https://github.com/dabeaz/curio/issues/176 for context.