# Merging async iterables in python3

Tags: python-3.x, reactive-programming, python-asyncio

Is there a good way, or a well-supported library, for merging async iterators in python3?

The desired behavior is basically the same as that of merging observables in reactivex.

That is, in the normal case, if I'm merging two async iterator, I want the resulting async iterator to yield results chronologically. An error in one of the iterators should derail the merged iterator.

[image: Merging Observables]

(Source: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html)

This is my best attempt, but it seems like something there might be a standard solution to:

```
async def drain(stream, q, sentinal=None):
    try:
        async for item in stream:
            await q.put(item)
        if sentinal:
            await q.put(sentinal)
    except BaseException as e:
        await q.put(e)


async def merge(*streams):

    q = asyncio.Queue()
    sentinal = namedtuple("QueueClosed", ["truthy"])(True)

    futures = {
        asyncio.ensure_future(drain(stream, q, sentinal)) for stream in streams
    }

    remaining = len(streams)
    while remaining > 0:
        result = await q.get()
        if result is sentinal:
            remaining -= 1
            continue
        if isinstance(result, BaseException):
            raise result
        yield result


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Example: Should print:
    #   1
    #   2
    #   3
    #   4

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    async def gen():
        yield 1
        await asyncio.sleep(1.5)
        yield 3

    async def gen2():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        yield 2
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        yield 4

    async def go():
        async for x in merge(gen(), gen2()):
            print(x)

    loop.run_until_complete(go())
```

Comment: how does the mergedelay resolve when two merge items arrive at the same time? does it randomly select one over the other

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [aiostream.stream.merge](http://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operators.html#aiostream.stream.merge):

```
from aiostream import stream

async def go():
    async for x in stream.merge(gen(), gen2()):
        print(x)
```

More examples in the [documentation](http://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44413302/2846140).

Comment: Those links are returning 404.

Comment: @samfrances Oops, fixed!